# Kohana v3 - Passing variables through Request::instance()->redirect()

Tags: variables, request, kohana-3

[Kohana v3] Is there any way to pass variables to the views through Request::instance()->redirect(). What would be a good alternative? Thanks!

Comment: could you elaborate a bit further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you call the redirect do these in your controller:

```
$success = "Your Email has send successfully";
    $session = Session::instance();
    $session->set('success', $success);
$this->redirect('contact-us', 302);
```

then in your view page to get the value you do these

```
<?php 
$session = Session::instance(); 
$success = $session->get_once('success'); 

    if (!empty($success)) : ?>
       <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success! </strong><?=$success?>
       </div>
    <?php endif;?>
```

that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Deceptively easy if this works for you:

`Request::instance()->redirect('/dashboard?err=incomplete');`

No reason you can't build the string using any number of $_GET parameters.